# Microstrategy bar chart

Tags: bar-chart, microstrategy

I have a mysql database table with integer RecordsRead field for example and I can bring this into a grid view and it looks correct.  But when I do a bar chart of the values 15, 30, and 45 I get the values at the bottom of my chart but each bar is the same size regardless of value.  I expected three different size bars in this case.

Any what might be wrong...

Comment: can you show us the definition of your chart and the grid? Are you using MicroStrategy web or desktop? Did you create a dashboard? In case did you put the metric value in the Vertical area?

Comment: desktop, I created a dossier, I connected my data to it from the mysql table.  I did try putting stop time at the horizontal and records read on the vertical.  And that gave me a grid of square blocks all the same size.  I have nothing in the sizeby field in the editor.  But I can't seem to put something there.  Defination of chart...don't know where to find that.

Comment: I was able to install tableau desktop and get what I needed.  So I stopped looking at microstrategy.